# My SSD seems slow, could it be the link speed?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd, performance, sata

I just replaced my old HD from a late-2009 iMac with a new Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB. 
It was installed by an official Apple repair store but I am worried because it seems slower than my new macboook pro (also with SSD)
I tested with Blackmagic Disk Test and it:

- Writes 253 MB/s
- Reads 268 Mb/s

[Official specs](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/ssd850evo/specifications.html) say it should:

- Write 520 MB/s
- Read 500 Mb/s

And it seems from [reviews](http://www.profesionalreview.com/2015/03/10/samsung-850-evo-ssd-review/) they get numbers close to official ones.

I checked my SATA Chipset in the iMac and it says: "Link Speed: 3 Gigabit".

Does this mean that 3000 Mb/s (Megabits) are 375 MB/s (Megabytes) and it cannot transfer faster (even though the SSD is faster)?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that TRIM is enabled. Without TRIM, SSDs will run slower. I use Trim Enabler to turn on TRIM on my Samsung SSDs.

https://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/

Nowadays it can enable TRIM without disabling kext signing.

https://www.cindori.org/safely-enable-trim-on-yosemite-and-el-capitan/